# Взять первые две триады из IP-адреса с помощью regexp

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как с помощью regexp из строки формата `::ffff:123.456.78.90` получить:

1. `123.456.`
2. `123.456.78.`

При этом `::ffff:` — всегда фикс, а IPv4-адрес соответствует формату IP-адресов (между точками могут быть от 1 до 3 цифр).

Comment: Проще, как мне кажется, сначала выкинуть первые `length('::ffff:')` символов, а затем сделать `split` по точке (ну если в языке, на котором вы пишите, есть `split` для строк)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = "::ffff:123.456.78.90"

console.log(s.match(/\d+\.\d+\./)[0])
console.log(s.match(/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\./)[0])

console.log(s.match(/((\d+)\.(\d+)\.)(\d+)\./))
```

Comment: Так наверное логичнее, чем 2 раза через шаблон прогонять? var match = s.match(/((\d+\.\d+\.)\d+\.)/); console.log(match[2]);; console.log(match[1]);

Comment: @MedvedevDev, я подумал, что это два разные вопроса... А логичнее, на мой взгляд, вообще сразу группы с числами достать из `/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/`. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Вот если каждое вытаскивать, тогда мне прям интересно, а не лучше ли сделать как откомментил под вопросом diraria ?

Comment: @MedvedevDev, не знаю. К тому же. мы не знаем, где он это использовать собирается - вдруг в каком-нибудь `sed`?

Answer (score 1):

::ffff:123.456.78.90

```
:(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})
```

Пример на perl:

```
perl -E '$a="::ffff:123.456.78.90"; $a=~/:(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/; say "$1.$2."; say "$1.$2.$3."'
123.456.
123.456.78.
```

Comment: группы то расставьте сразу, чтобы ответ желаемый получить.